# unable to drag and drop file form Outlook (2013) to Salesforce Files

Tags: chatter, chatter-file

I am able to drag and drop (D&D) files from my windows explorer windows (tested .docx and .pdf files) into Salesforce however I am not able to drag a PDF from my Outlook email message into Salesforce. Specifically I am dragging the file into the Chatter | Files page, which prompts the user to "Drag &Drop here". Is this a limitation?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is either a limitation of your Outlook client, or your Operating System, rather than being a limitation on the Salesforce side.

The drag and drop events are handled by your browser, which in its turn gets it from the operating system. So in this case the browser doesn't get a drag-event from the OS and in its turn can't forward the drag-event to the webpage.

Comment: That's right. You have to drag to the file system first and then go from there to the browser. This is a desktop app to browser issue for everyone.

Comment: Thanks, I have added it to Salesforce Ideas (https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DftbAAC)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to fix this from within Salesforce. You need to use a third-party utility like http://www.outlook2web.com/

Comment: The Outlook plugin one my team found worked best after testing was [this one](https://www.wilutions.info/ddaddin-download.html), which was most consistent across browsers (issues with Edge for the above) and is also affordable

Comment: FYI - It is possible to drag and drop email from Outlook into Salesforce Lightning now, by directly dragging them onto the "Files" component.